# How can I keep stable position of my drone? How can I detect bias of them?

Tags: imu, mems

I am just a little bit worried about my research because I feel stuck in one point and I can't find the exit door.

My question is about this:

I will design a drone and the professor wants that drone keeps its angles in one position. That is, roll, pitch and yaw angles don't change. How can I keep them in a stable position?  Or, how can I detect bias of them?  I am thinking about using IMU or MEMS-INS for this.

Am I on the right path?

Comment: Stabilization of roll, pitch, and yaw *angles* as described in the body of your question is a feature of $12 toys.  But that is not *position* stabilization - the latter is quite challenging, and often the fancy demos you see are done with external cameras and computing.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/betaflight
It should answer all your questions - and a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

With a..

- 3 DOF (Degrees of freedom) mems (**Accelerator**) you can calculate the angles (if your drone is stationary).
- 3 DOF mems (**Gyroscope**) you can calculate the angles (this will drift)
- 3 DOF mems (**Magnetometer**) you can calculate the angles (which might be distorted by large heavy/soft iron objects)

If you take the information from all 9 sources = 9 DOF simultaneously you get something called [sensor fusion (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensor_fusion), [Here's a tutorial about this at adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/ahrs-for-adafruits-9-dof-10-dof-breakout/sensor-fusion-algorithms).

In an ideal world where the fusion works perfectly, you end up with something called [AHRS (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attitude_and_heading_reference_system) (not arse) which stands for "Attitude & Heading Reference System".

AHRS modules used to be very pricey, but just recently, about a month ago, I came across the [GY-955 module (aliexpress)](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/GY-955-Kalman-Filter-AHRS-Sensor-9-Axis-9-Axis-Tilt-Compensation-Navigation-Module-Acceleration-Gyroscope/32838969631.html) which even comes with integrated kalman filter, the kalman filter gives a good estimate for what the real AHRS value actually is.

I haven't tried the GY-955 module so I can't say how good it is, or if it's just Chinese bogus marketing. But if I were you I would just take the easy route and acquire a GY-955 module and call it a day.

---

If you want to keep the drone geographically stable then you will most likely also have to add a GPS module to it, or some other sensor that relates to the physical real world.